# How to change fits images' angular resolution in astropy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, resolution, astronomy, fits

I have two fits image of different wavelength. They have different angular resolution.
I want to convolve the higher resolution image to the lower one.
I have tried astropy.convolution.convolve and astropy.convolution.Gaussian2DKernel.
Resolution is 0.184" for 1600nm, and 0.124" for 606nm. So I think the resolution for the kernel should be 0.136". Then I tried following code:

```
import os
from astropy.io import fits  
from astropy.convolution import Gaussian2DKernel  
from astropy.convolution import convolve  
  
kernel = Gaussian2DKernel(x_stddev=0.136)   
hdu = fits.open('/Users/lpr/Data/fits/pridata/goodsn_f606/606.fits')[0]  
img = hdu.data  
astropy_conv = convolve(img,kernel)  
hdu.data = astropy_conv  
hdu.writeto('/Users/lpr/Data/fits/expdata/CONVOLIMAGE/convolved_606.fits')  
print('done')
```

Of course, that's wrong. The resolution of higher one(606) almost unchanged. Then I realize that I convolve two different type thing. One is flux(or electrons/s), the other is kernel.

Now I don't know how to match the higher resolution image to lower one. Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first issue is that the standard deviation of your kernel should be in pixels, not in arcseconds.

Then you may be interested in two packages that allow to compute the matching kernel between two PSFs:

- the first one is in *photutils*: https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/psf_matching.html
- the second one is a dedicated package: https://pypher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I tried to set standard deviation = 2.288(pixel scale=0.059''/pixel). But the result image become smoother than 160 image.

Comment: The standard deviation in Gaussian2DKernel cannot be used directly in astropy.convolution.convolve. I compare two kernel generated by photutils and Gaussian2DKernel, they are very different. Firstly, photutils generate a kernel with the same size of source image, but, we can set size of kernel in Gaussian2DKernel.(That makes some difficult when source size is even.) Finally, the number in these two kernel are very different. But i succeed when source image size is odd. Thank you very much. This problem confused me for two week, now i have some idea.

Comment: The kernel generated by photutils and pypher are similar(final result is good). So, i think my initial method is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you cannot convolve directly with a Gaussian, because the resulting PSF would be the sum of your source one and of the kernel one. So what photutils and pypher basically do is to compute the kernel that would deconvolve from your source PSF and reconvolve by the target one, using the ratio of Fourier transforms.